# How to use FileInputStream for accessing an input file from another class?

Tags: java, input, file-io, inputstream, user-input

here are the two java classes:

to get the input file:

```
public class Inputfile {    

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = null;
    boolean isFile = false;
    while (isFile == false){   
        System.out.print("Input file name? ");
        String fileName = sc.next();

        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        if (inputFile.exists()){
            input = new Scanner(inputFile);
            isFile = true;
        }            
    }
```

to parse the input file:

```
public class PdfParse {

public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception  {



Inputfile inputfile = new Inputfile();
 String fileName;
 fileName =  inputfile.toString();      
  FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File("fileName"));


ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
  .........   
  }
```

all i get is FileNotfound Exception for filename. 
I tried to using the string name but i couldn't get the string name from inputfile class using getters but i failed. can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your `getFileName` method in your `Inputfile` class

```
 public class Inputfile {    

      public static String getFileName() throws Exception  {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fileName = null;
        boolean isFile = false;
        while (!isFile){   
            System.out.print("Input file name? ");
            fileName = sc.next();

            File inputFile = new File(fileName);
            if (inputFile.exists()){
                isFile = true;
            }            
        } 
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

And then you can use above defined method in `main` method of `PdfParse` class

```
  public class PdfParse {

      public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception  {



        String fileName = InputFile.getFileName();

        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));


         ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();
         .........   
      } 
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where are you getting `NullPointerException` ?

Comment: Got it... Try it now

Comment: fileName returned is null (i just printed that from PdfParse class) .
how to correct it?

Comment: That was because `fileName` was declared twice and outer `fileName` was getting to other class which was `null` .. i have already corrected that

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the file to the second class:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
File inputFile = null;
while (inputFile == null){   
    System.out.print("Input file name? ");
    String fileName = sc.next();

    inputFile = new File(fileName);
    if (!inputFile.exists()){
        inputFile = null;
    }            
}

PdfParse.parse(input); // <-- Pass file to parser
```

Then your `PdfParse` class could look like this:

```
public class PdfParse {

    public static void parse(File inputFile) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks,Jorn! but the other answer was simpler. :)